# Dynamically set sproc name in Linq to SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I need to dynamically set the sproc name of a Linq to SQL query and can't figure out how. I see in the dbml designer that the sproc name is an attribute but it must be a constant, so I can't set it to a dynamic value. Please help.
Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out, the answer is to use dataContext.ExecuteQuery or dataContext.ExecuteCommand.